# AndroidRuntime error ClassNotFoundException when I use Android Library (AAR)

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, aar

I build an AAR library and add to my android project.

It compile success but when I run the app, it show error:

```
... AndroidRuntime: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.application.R.layout"
```

Then I extract the AAR library, there is no R.Class in class.jar.

Is there anyone have same issue like me? Do you know how to generate R.Class in AAR library to avoid this problem?

Comment: Please try to delete this from lib and reimport this aar file again from another path, and also check where you have define it properly in gradle like implementation files('libs/xyz.aar')              or check the path of R.layout with package this idea may help you

Comment: @Ghanshyam Thank you. I do like you said, and clean/rebuild project. Then app works, this error is not shown. But I don't know what is the root cause. There is still no R.Class in class.jar so why these classes can link to each other.

Comment: R class not package in Jar the library project not generate R class they depend on. Only application projects generates the Library R classes alongside their own. I have updated it in detailed solution about this problem in answer below to help some another person also, please check

Comment: Refer to httpsstackoverflow.comquestions34915501aar-support-in-android-mk-the-apk-contain-no-r-java-which-packagename-is-aar

Answer (score -1):

Please try to delete this from lib and reimport this aar file again from another path, and also check where you have define it properly in gradle like implementation files('libs/xyz.aar') and clean builds or check the path of R.layout with package this idea may help you

The R class is not packaged in the jar output of Library Projects anymore. Library Project do not generate the R class for Library Projects they depend on. Only main application projects generates the Library R classes alongside their own

Please go to below link

http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects